# MPMoviePlayerController showing black screen in iOS 5 only

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios-simulator, mpmovieplayercontroller

I m downloading a aac file and playing it in MPMoviePlayerController with following code

```
movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.filePath]];
[self.view addSubview:movieController.view];
CGRect screenBound = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = screenBound.size;
movieController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
[movieController setFullscreen:YES];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doneBtnMediaPlayer:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
```

movieController is (nonatomic,strong) class property

this works fine in all iOSes except iOS 5 (and iOS 5 simulator).
In iOS 5 it shows black screen and file is played in background.

Another thing i have noticed is, when i run application over already existing app then its works fine on iOS5 also. But when i delete app from device and then run it, at that time it just shows black screen.

Comment: Dec 2013 .. TIP - it is hugely flakey about file name extensions (files form the net). In my app, .MOV works, .mov crashes the iPhone hard.  Bizarre.  Also the simulator simply doesn't work, it's totally useless and just crashes.  Finally on the MPMoviePlayerViewController approach works, MPMoviePlayerController is useless and broken.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

this is your header (.h) file
    #import 
    #import

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic,retain)MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerController;

@end
```

and this is your implementation file (.m)
    #import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize playerController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gold etche" ofType:@"mov"]];
playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerController];
[self.view insertSubview:playerController.view atIndex:0];
playerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
playerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
playerController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;

[playerController.moviePlayer play];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

I tested this in IOS 5 (5.0 AND 5.1) AND IOS 6 AND EVERYTHING SEEMS TO BE FINE

Comment: Thanks for quick reply if i use this code then after playback ViewController gets popped out. To avoid that i removed its observer then i dont find any way to remove VC as done button dosen't do anything.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this is the only solution, thanks :D

Comment: Glad it helped. I'd really appreciate your vote up to my answer.